# differenche between Inject Parent component and use @Input() in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-decorator

Hi which is the difference between Inject the parent component into the child componet and use the @Input() decorator? Is there any performance difference?

**PARENT**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'a-comp',
  template: `<b-comp [text]="text"></b-comp>`
}) 
export class AppComponent{
public text = 'some Text';
}
```

**Child**

```
@Component({
 selector: 'b-comp',
 template: `<span>{{ text }}</span>`
      }) 
  export class BComponent {
      @Input() text;
      constructor() {}
}
```

**PARENT**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'a-comp',
  template: `<b-comp ></b-comp>`
      }) 
  export class AppComponentt {
public text = 'some Text';

}
```

**Child**

```
@Component({
 selector: 'b-comp',
template: `<span>{{ text }}</span>`
    }) 
 export class BComponentt {
   public text = this.parent.text;
    constructor(private parent: AppComponent) {}
       }
```

Comment: I don't see @Input in your code sample. How did you config it?

Comment: sorry this is only case two (inject parent component)